# Ignore value from assoc array when display

Tags: php, associative-array

```
    $result = mysql_query($sql_result);
    $newArray = array();
    $index=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $newArray[$index] = $row;   
        $index++;
    }
```

I wanna ignore the value - from my assoc array when display. Help me please.[image]

Comment: Don't `SELECT` it then. Avoid `SELECT * FROM SomeWhere`, use column names instead of `*`.

Comment: if its only "-" you want to ignore why don't you do a condition check and replace it with something else when you display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all columns containing a certain value you could use array_filter:

```
function removeEmpty($v){
   return $v != '-';
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $newArray[$index] = array_filter($row,"removeEmpty");   
        $index++;
}
```

Comment: removing misunderstanding.